# PosrgteSQL: the sum of the column values for the period depending on the step (day, month, year)

Tags: laravel, postgresql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I want to create a stored procedure or function that returns a sum of the column values for the period depending on the step (day, month, year). For example, I have table with consumption data. It saves data every 15 minutes. I would like to get report for period from 2019-05-01 to 2019-05-10 with step '1 day'. I need to define a daily dataset for each of the days in this interval and get the sum of the values for each day.

Then the procedure returns data to Laravel. Based on this data charts are built.

My code for this moment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."test"("meterid" int4, "started" text, "ended" text, "preiod" text)
  RETURNS TABLE("_kwh" numeric, "datetime" timestamp) AS $BODY$BEGIN

    RETURN QUERY

    SELECT kwh, a_datetime 
    FROM "public"."consumption" 
    WHERE meter_id = meterid 
    AND a_datetime 
        BETWEEN to_timestamp(started, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
        AND to_timestamp(ended, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pg_generate_series(start, end, interval)`

More information in: [set returning functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)

To simulate your situation I created a simple table:

```
postgres=# create table consumption (kwh int, datetime date);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into consumption values (10, 2019-01-01);
ERROR:  column "datetime" is of type date but expression is of type integer
postgres=# insert into consumption values (10, '2019-01-01');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into consumption values (2, '2019-01-03');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into consumption values (24, '2019-03-06');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into consumption values (30, '2019-03-22');
INSERT 0 1
```

And made the select with `generate_series()`

```
postgres=# SELECT COALESCE(SUM(kwh), 0) AS kwh, 
                  period::DATE     
             FROM GENERATE_SERIES('2019-01-01','2019-12-31', '1 day'::interval) AS period
        LEFT JOIN consumption ON period::DATE=datetime::DATE 
         GROUP BY 2

 kwh |   period   
-----+------------
   0 | 2019-04-17
   0 | 2019-05-29
   ....
   0 | 2019-04-06
   0 | 2019-04-26
   2 | 2019-01-03
   0 | 2019-03-15
   ...
   0 | 2019-11-21
   0 | 2019-07-24
  30 | 2019-03-22
   0 | 2019-05-22
   0 | 2019-11-19
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks. It's almost what i need. But instead of the amount for the day, I get the first value for that day. Thanks anyway

Comment: You need only the first_value for that day? If yes, I edit the answer and show how to use window functions to solve this.

Comment: I need the amaunt of consumption per day (sorry for my English). Lets say, I have [table](http://prntscr.com/q53eyi). So, for 2018-05-01 it's will be amount of all records per this day: 5,52 + 4,32 + 2,16 + 2,4 + 2,41 ... And same for each day of period

Comment: Ok, I understood. You are using timestamp. On the column `period` on example, I defined that column is a type `DATE`. The date solve this. Note that in your result you have the date and also the time.

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks! Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to mark your answer as useful.